# linker error in C++ (again)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

so I needing some help with creating a program for my class. The lab requires us to use pointers.
This is the description of what we have to do...

-Write a function that accepts an int array and the array's size as arguments.
-The program should ask the size of the array and lets the users enter some integer values.
-The function should create a new array that is one element larger than the argument array.
-The first element of the array should be set to 0.
-Element 0 of the argument array should be copied to element 1 of the new array.
-Element 1 of the argument array should be copied to element 2 of the new array, etc.
-The function should return a pointer to the new array.
-There should be three other functions: getMode, getMedian and getAverage.
-These functions should get Mode, Median and Average of the values within an array.
-You should display the argument array and the new array as well as the mode, median and the average.

This is what I have so far I'm not sure if its right. Any help is greatly appreciated.
UPDATE: I run the program and it asks the user for the size of the array and the values for it...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int* addToSize (int*, int);

using namespace std;


int main()
{   

    int userSize=0; //Holds user size
    int userInts; //Holds uaer values
    int *memory; //dynamically allocate an array


    //int  *intptr;
    //int *arrayNew;
    //int newA;

    //Gets array size
    cout << "Please enter the array size!" << endl;
    cin >> userSize; 

    //Memory array 
    memory = new int [userSize];

    //Grab values for the amount of user size 
    for (int count = 0; count < userSize; count ++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the value for " << count+1 << endl;
        cin >> userInts;
    }


    for (int index = 0; index < userSize; index ++)
    {
        cin >> memory[index];
    }

    //Sets addToSize function to memory array
    memory = addToSize(memory, userSize);

   //Shows memory array
    for(int index=0;index< (userSize + 1);index++)
        cout<<memory[index]<<endl;

    delete[] memory;    //Used to delete memory array
    memory = 0; //sets memory array to 0

    return 0;

}


    int* addToSize(int* arrayNew, int newSize) 
{
    int* expandSize= new int [newSize +1];

    for (int index = 0; index < newSize; index++)
    {
        expandSize[index]= arrayNew[index];
    }
    for (int index = newSize; index < (newSize+1); index ++) 
    {
        expandSize[index]=0;
    }   
    return expandSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have *declared* a forward reference to some `addToSize()` function which accepts 2 arguments, and you proceed to invoke it from within your `main()`, and that's all very fine and dandy, but then further down you *define* an `addToSize()` which accepts 3 arguments.

So, what is happening is that the declared function is unrelated to the defined function.  The compiler completely ignores the 3-argument function, since you are not calling it, and it assumes that you will provide a definition for the two-parameter function in some other source file.

But then when the linker attempts to link your program, there is no other file containing an `addToSize()` with two arguments, so the linker fails with an error message which describes precisely what happened.  (It is a linker error. It has nothing to do with pointers and arrays.)

Hint: before fixing your function definition to match the declaration, lose the forward declaration, move the function to the start of the file, and make it `static`.

Comment: Okay so I have fixed the addToSize function and only put it to accept 2 arguments. The program now runs and asks the user for the size of the array and the values

Comment: Great.  Upvote the correct answer, accept it, and happy programming!

Comment: Question, how do I set the element of the first array to 0 and then copy  elements 0 and 1 etc.. of the argument array to the new array?